# check if two lists differ for an element

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
list1=['h', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'p']
list2=['e', 'h', 'c', 'n', 'p', 'o']
```

I want my function `diff1` to return true if these two lists differ for exactly one element

in this case `diff1` return `True` because `list2` has a 'c'

I can assume `list2` has always exactly one more element than `list1`

thanks you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) of sets:

> symmetric_difference(other)
>
> set ^ other
>
> Return a new set with elements
>   in either the set or other but not both.

```
list1=['h', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'p']
list2=['e', 'h', 'c', 'n', 'p', 'o']

sym_diff = set(list1).symmetric_difference(list2)
print(sym_diff)
# {'c'}
```

And you just need to check if this difference contains one item:

```
one_different = len(sym_diff) == 1
print(one_different)
# True
```

Comment: doesn't work if list2 contains two equals letters, such as: list2=['e', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'p', 'o']